# Assign alias email domain names in Gmail

Tags: gmail

At my university, the email addresses `name@newcastle.ac.uk` and `name@ncl.ac.uk` 
are the same. This makes things a bit messy in Gmail, since the contacts now have two email addresses, and when searching for an email I have to include both email addresses in the search bar.

Is it possible to create some sort of alias, so that Gmail treats `newcastle.ac.uk` as `ncl.ac.uk`?

Answer (score 3):

Basically, what you're requesting is to use *labels*, which is meant to work that way. Here's an idea:

- Add a filter for both (`from:newcastle.ac.uk` and `from:ncl.ac.uk`) to automatically add a label (maybe [newcastle](/questions/tagged/newcastle) in this case).

Then you'll be able to search for `from:name in:label` like: `from:John in:newcastle`.

Answer (score -1):

You could try to create a contact that has all these alias emails as their email adresses, that way you can search for the contact and all messages with it…